# WebView "disabled" in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I just upgraded my app to Windows 8.1, but now pages that I am loading into the WebView are no longer interactive. I can't press any buttons or fill out any HTML form fields. My WebView looks like this

```
<WebView x:Name="browser" ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"></WebView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just created a new Windows Store app for Windows 8.1 based on the `Blank App (XAML)` template only putting the following line inside the `Grid` of `MainPage.xaml`:

```
<WebView x:Name="browser" ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Source="http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_form_code.cfm" />
```

The HTML form controls behave as expected. Does this work for you? Do you have anything else on your page that could prevent interaction with HTML controls?

Maybe you have other (transparent) controls over the `WebView`. There's a change in z-ordering in Windows 8.1: in Windows 8 `WebView` was always rendered on top of other controls, now it can be rendered under other controls.

Comment: You're right, I did have another control on top of my WebView.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just put the WebView with an Rectangle in a Grid and it seems that all the inputs are captured by the Rectangle:

```
                <Grid>
                <WebView Name="ContentWebView" ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Disabled" 
                     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                     DefaultBackgroundColor="Transparent" Height="Auto" MinHeight="600" />
                <Rectangle Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>

            </Grid>
```

Answer (score -2):

U should navigate webview or set source as explained above. Blank webview does not show anything

browser.navigate("http://example.com//");