# Windows 8.1 webview interaction and scrolling issue

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-8, webview, windows-8.1

I have a basic webview:

```
<WebView x:Name="webView1" Grid.Row="1"  Margin="75,0,40,40"/>
```

The code behind is as follows:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        webView1.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.bbc.co.uk/news"));
    }
```

The webview displays, but it does not scroll or allow you to click on any of the links (basically no interaction with in the BBC website).

I have made a completely blank test project and stuck this in the page to test it, but it works fine. So there is clearly an issue with my real project.

I have compared the manifest settings of my project and the working test project, but they appear the same.

Would there be some security setting somewhere? I can't see why my project would handle the webview differently to the test project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After finding a similar question, [WebView “disabled” in Windows 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434442/webview-disabled-in-windows-8-1), I went back to my project to see if I had any transparent layers over the top of my webview, preventing the interaction.

I looked at the visual tree using [XAML Spy](http://xamlspy.com/) software. There was nothing there. I then realised that XAML Spy itself was there! So I disabled XAML Spy in the project, and the webview now works!

So XAML Spy must put a transparent layer over the top of your application, which obviously prevents webview interaction. I will log that as a bug with XAML Spy. Hopefully they will be able to fix it.

Comment: tnx Daisy, saved my day

Comment: Glad I helped. It was pretty frustrating. :-)

Comment: The same is also true if you are using the Live Visual Tree from VS 2015. Be sure to disable the layout adorners if you want to interact with the webview.

Comment: @Daisy I'd agree I think that's a bug in XAML Spy v annoying.